# How to write and save to a document in Python 3.4?

Tags: python, file, input

I've been trying to make a simple program to save user data (such as a level or stat) and so far nothing I've found online works.

```
test = open("sketch_pad.py","w")
test.write("This is a test\nOr is it?")
test.close
```

This brings up an error, along the lines of "Not writable file" (despite the fact that it is a .py)
Either this, or it will erase all the data in the document "sketch_pad.py", and not write anything.

Comment: `close` is a function and needs `()` at the end as in `close()`

Comment: Why are you writing to a Python file.

Comment: The .py shouldn't matter - you can open .txt or .dat or .exe just as easily, so something else is going on.

Comment: Wow - Thank you. Easy thing to overlook

Comment: Are you writing strings or actual Python objects like dictionaries or lists? You might want to use pickle in that case. I think you're getting confused.

Answer (score 4):

Close method should be called (`f.close()`). To avoid these kind of mistakes and ensure releasing resources on errors/exceptions you may consider using Python [with statement](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/), e.g.

```
with open("file.txt","w") as f:
    f.write("data")
```

Answer (score 0):

[`close`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_close.htm) is a method and should be called as such; `f.close()` is the correct syntax, currently you are omitting the brackets `()`.

```
test = open("sketch_pad.py","w")
test.write("This is a test\nOr is it?")
test.close() # you need these brackets
```

should work.

You can dodge these kinds of mistakes by using [Python's with statement](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm):

```python
with open("myFile.txt", "w") as myFile:
    myFile.write("data")

# no need for myFile.close(),
# it is called automatically.
```